# Can the /home and /swap partitions be on a different disks than the / (root) partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am in the process of dual-booting my Windows 10 PC to also run Ubuntu 20.04 on it. I have both a 240 GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. The SSD is for the Windows 10 OS, and the HDD is for my files/documents/everything else.

I have just freed up 40 GB on the SSD and 200 GB on the HDD to install Ubuntu. My question is, can I create the "/" partition on the SSD and the "/swap" and "/home" partitions on the HDD? If so, how?

I am very new to Linux, so please provide step-by-step solution.

Comment: Questions on Mint should be asked on [unix.se].

Comment: You can have any of the partitions on any of the disks, as long as GRUB is installed on the disk which is given boot priority.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I will remember that for future questions. I completely forgot that this was for Ubuntu, despite the name! My apologies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES YOU CAN** , Just start the ubuntu installation setup and when you reach partitioning menu , 'Do Something Else' (or manual partitioning). Here you will be able to make partitions on whichever disk you want and then assign them as 'swap space' or '/home'. just be sure to make a '/' too ( This is where rest of your os will go ). Good luck.

Comment: OK, have done this, and will hopefully be lucky. Thanks!
P.S. Do I need a "/root"?

Comment: No you don't not unless you want use ubuntu as root user. '/root' as acts as '/home' for root user.

Comment: So I should only need those 3 partitions? This is eventually to be my web development PC, in case that matters. I've been Windows-bound until now.

Comment: Yea, those 3 partitions will be fine, also because you will have a separate '/home' you will be able change or install new linux without losing personal data stored in '/home'